# Regression and contrast codings with multiple categorical variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

In regression with multiple explanatory categorical variables, how should I model the problem to compare the effects of the categorical variables with each other?

Most [contrast coding schemes](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm) (e.g. also [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable#Categorical_variables_and_regression)) seem to be designed (or at least, that's how they are described) to compare the effects of different levels **within** a given categorical variable (e.g. German vs British nationality). But what if I want to compare contributions **between** categorical variables?

For example, say that we want to estimate the contribution of two explanatory categorical variables (dress size and color) to a single dependent variable (dress price). How can I design my coding to measure interpretable contributions of **size** and **color** to price?

Answer (score 1):

Reference cell coding:

There are P categorical variables with N levels each. This will generate P*(N-1) dummies where some combination of levels of categories is selected as baseline and others are estimated in relation to it. Baseline could be S and Green for example. Coding is done by having 0/1 indicator for N-1 levels each.

Deviation from the mean coding is such that sum of codes is zero for N levels.

Comment: Thanks. I am still missing some level of detail on how to do this. Assuming that you have `P(N-1)` dummies (i.e. using one level per variable as a reference level), after fitting, how do I estimate the contribution of a full variable?